# Display 1 to 10 without using loop scilab

Tags: scilab

Just started using Scilab, looks like a lot to learn but I am stuck at very first basic program. I need to display 1 to 10 numbers without using loop.
I know that using loop we can use this code to display numbers from 1 to 10:

```
for i = 1:10
disp(i)
end
```

But i need to display them without using any loop. In C programming it's a bit easy using recursive function but here i have tried alot and failed.
Please can any one help me out via code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think  a recursive call is still kind of a loop, but it could be done like this:

```
function recursivePrint(i, maxNumber)

     if( i <= maxNumber )
         disp(i)
         recursivePrint(i+1, maxNumber)
     end

endfunction

recursivePrint(1, 10);
```

Usually when people ask to write a function without a loop they mean something like:

```
disp(1:10)
```

Comment: where did u learn all this any good tutorial or source plz share :) ... nice program

Comment: @iPhnQ you can take a look at [this document](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/docintrotoscilab/downloads/311/) and just start programming. I did some [projecteuler problems](http://www.projecteuler.net) to keep me busy.

Answer (score -2):

```
disp(1)
disp(2)
disp(3)
disp(4)
disp(5)
disp(6)
disp(7)
disp(8)
disp(9)
disp(10)
```

Curious what you tried..

Comment: like in C we use: #include
int main()
{
static int i=1;
if(i<=100)
{
printf("%d",i);
i++;
main();
}

return(getchar());
}

Comment: For one thing that's not a valid C program, and for another you shouldn't downvote an answer that does what you need.

Comment: will you write 100 line of code if printing 1 to 100? It's not the correct way. I am not the only one to downvote.